# r.net nuget package not updated since 2020

Tags: c#, r.net

It seems that r.net has not been updated since 2020.

1. Does anyone know of any plans to update this software?
2. Is the current version, 1.9.0, compatible with VS2022 on Windows 10?  If not is there another recommended way to call R functions from C# .NET?

Currently I am using R.NET successfully with VS2019.

Comment: _"Is the current version, 1.9.0, compatible with VS2022 on Windows 10"_ - the easiest way to check would be to just try, but since it targets .NET Standard then there is a high chance that it will work with latest VS.